# Сортировка массива методом вставки в несколько потоков

Tags: массивы, c, алгоритм, c++

Какие идеи есть, чтобы отсортировать массив элементов в n потоков методом вставки?

Comment: Честно говоря, первая идея - придумать что-нибудь получше параллельной сортировки вставкой.

Comment: 1. Не нужно повторять уже заданные [вопросы](http://hashcode.ru/questions/152261/c-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2). 2. В WinAPI я лично не нашел ф-ций для сортировки массивов. 3. И поэтому сформулируйте задачу корректнее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делим массив на n частей, сортируем каждую в отдельном потоке "вставками", а частичные результаты сливаем в один "слиянием", которое так же можно рекурсивно распараллеливать, если надо.

Comment: В этом случае всю сортировку  надо делать слиянием. Параллельно `n` частей, затем уменьшая степень параллелизма сливаем их в результат. 

Собственно сортировка вставками здесь будет присутствовать, когда в процессе деления каждой из `n` частей (непосредственно перед слиянием) мы начнем получать уже совсем маленькие (два-три десятка элементов) отрезки.

Дело тут в том, что сортировка слиянием (непараллельная) имеет сложность O(N log N) и требует порядка N/2 вспомогательной памяти, а сортировка вставками O(N^2) (но без вспомогательной памяти).

Т.е. от этих N/2 дополнительной памяти не убежать.

Comment: @avp, в таком случае, самый лучший вариант - использовать для сортировки не "вставки" и не "слияние", а быструю сортировку. Она чаще будет давать наилучшее время, поскольку исходная последовательность статична, т.е. не требует модификации во время сортировки. Вставки удобны, когда исходный набор "приходит" постепенно, поэлементно. А слияние удобно именно для слияния, что в данном случае и происходит с частичными результатами. Но если Вы исходите из сложности реализации такого алгоритма, то конечно, проще будет реализовать все слиянием.

Comment: @mega, quicksort неустойчивая сортировка, а вставки и слияние - устойчивые. Это может быть принципиально. 

Из устойчивых сортировок в общем случае видимо лучшей является сортировка слиянием (или ее модификации типа timsort).

Для чисел (небольшой размер ключа) самой быстрой (при достаточно большом N) будет radixsort (но требуется дополнительно N памяти).

Некоторый набор сортировок и их измерения (для linux) можете взять [здесь](http://code.google.com/p/yamsort/)

Comment: Не так важно, что устойчивее, важнее то, как будут обрабатываться частично отсортированные последовательности. И вставки и слияние собирают отсортированный массив, а быстрая сортировка его просто модифицирует, поэтому не требует и дополнительной памяти (не считая стека) да и устойчивость можно подправить, если нужно.

Comment: @mega, [Устойчивая (стабильная) сортировка — сортировка, которая не меняет относительный порядок сортируемых элементов, имеющих одинаковые ключи](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) - почитайте, а заодно и ознакомьтесь с алгоритмами по ссылкам в конце статьи.

По поводу сбора-модификации массива, если уж использовать такую терминологию, то вставки и quicksort модифицируют массив по месту, а слияние, да пересобирает.

Comment: @avp, я всегда считал устойчивостью - стабильность оценки времени работы алгоритма, так что не надо меня тыкать в википедию, а по поводу сборки и модификации массива, подумайте хорошенько над разницей между этими понятиями. Если алгоритм вставками можно реализовать на том же массиве данных, это еще не значит, что он не будет пересобран, так что Ваши домыслы о стабильности этого алгоритма ошибочны.

Comment: @mega, Вы можете, конечно, использовать свои понятия, но скорее всего другие люди будут неправильно Вас понимать.

--

Если использовать определение устойчивости (стабильности) алгоритма сортировки из википедии (и кучи других источников), то сортировка вставками является стабильной (устойчивой). Можете проверить экспериментально, можете прочесть, например у Кнута в т. 3.

Comment: Ну, хорошо. Опять возвращаемся к тому что было: Ваше понятие устойчивости ни как не влияет на сборку массива, о которой я говорю изначально, т.к. порядок следования элементов в сортировке вставками соблюдается переносом этих элементов в любом случае, а в быстрой сортировке этот порядок соблюдается без переноса, это очень важное качество алгоритма, т.к. объем перемещаемых данных на вставках составляет 100%, исключая первый элемент, в отличие от быстрой сортировки или любой другой сортировки с аналогичным свойством, поэтому она здесь наиболее приемлема.

Comment: Вставки не будут перемещать элементы только в исключительных ситуациях, когда последовательность уже отсортирована и опорный элемент берется с определенного конца этой последовательности, в зависимости от направления сортировки.

Answer (score 1):

[@mega](/users/8766/mega), вот ведь беда с этим лимитом комментариев. Приходится в ответе на вопрос отвечать на Ваш комментарий.

```
Ну, хорошо. Опять возвращаемся к тому что было: Ваше понятие устойчивости ни как не влияет на сборку массива, о которой я говорю изначально, т.к. порядок следования элементов в сортировке вставками соблюдается переносом этих элементов в любом случае, а в быстрой сортировке этот порядок соблюдается без переноса, это очень важное качество алгоритма, т.к. объем перемещаемых данных на вставках составляет 100%, исключая первый элемент, в отличие от быстрой сортировки или любой другой сортировки с аналогичным свойством, поэтому она здесь наиболее приемлема.
```

1. В сортировке вставками элемент перемещают (обменом с предыдущим (для сортировки по возрастанию)) до тех пор, пока он меньше предыдущего. Если не ошибаюсь в среднем получится (N^2)/4 обменов. В случае уже упорядоченного массива обменов вообще не будет. Для массивов в которых много уже упорядоченных последовательностей число обменов будет мало.
2. Совершенно не понял фразу: "...а в быстрой сортировке этот порядок соблюдается без переноса"

Вы считаете, что элемент массива, выбранный в качестве разделяющего не перемещается (путем обменов) по массиву?

Уверяю Вас, перемещается, ровно столько раз, сколько слева от него (после очередного обмена) оказывается больший или справа меньший. Другой вопрос, что в случае quicksort эти перемещнеия делят массив пополам (ну, это в идеале) и дальше перемещения (**и сравнения!**) проводятся только в уже разделенных частях. Именно поэтому (обязательно надо учтитывать количество сравнений) сложность quicksort будет O(N log N).

Comment: Вы, кстати, отвечаете на ответ, а не на вопрос.

>Уверяю Вас, перемещается, ровно столько раз, сколько слева от него (после очередного обмена) оказывается больший или справа меньший. Другой вопрос, что в случае quicksort эти перемещнеия делят массив пополам (ну, это в идеале) и дальше перемещения (и сравнения!) проводятся только в уже разделенных частях

т.е. в quicksort перемещений получается меньше. И в чем спор? Я именно об этом и говорю.

Comment: Да, видимо спор ни о чем. Началось с сравнения устойчивых и неустойчивых алгоритмов и их применимости.

А, вообще-то, вопрос автора темы так и остался неотвеченным.

 --

IMHO эффективно параллельную сортировку вставками (в существующих системах) никак не реализовать.

Comment: Реализовать частично параллельно может и можно, например: с блокировкой результирующей последовательности при обращении к ней потока на все время поиска места для каждого элемента, т.е. получится n блокировок массива, и это будет крайне неэффективно. Это можно сделать даже на быстрых взаимоблокировках, но суть от этого не поменяется - алгоритм будет работать скорее медленнее однопоточного.

Comment: Либо это будет сильно жадный алгоритм, если для каждой позиции элемента держать индекс его положения в массиве, и блокировать только отдельные элементы, но не думаю, что выигрыш будет стоить даже времени, потраченного на его разработку.